# Getting typeface and Windows name of font that is not installed

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-7

Can someone tell me how can I get the typeface name of a font? And how can I take the Windows name of the font having the typeface name?

Like "arialblackno1.ttf" that have typeface "arialblack".

but I am looking to get the typeface name of a font that isn't installed, it is just in a folder.

Comment: Interesting use of the code formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in a comment that you need the name of a font that isn't installed in Windows.

There are two ways of doing this that I can think of:-

- Use [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org)
- Or, use GDI+, and [PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Either way, you will need to find Delphi wrappers for these libraries. Google should help.

There seems to be a FreeType binding as part of [AggPas](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/aggpas-download.htm). It's not something I've tried, though.

Comment: Do you know any wrappers for delphi 7 for freetype project anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i have a little idea about what exactly are you asking (terms!)

```
procedure TForm14.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DC: HDC;
  Font: HFONT;
  LogFont: TLogFont;
begin
  DC := GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
  Win32Check(DC <> 0);
  Font := GetCurrentObject(DC, OBJ_FONT);
  Win32Check(Font <> 0);
  Win32Check(GetObject(Font, SizeOf(LogFont), @LogFont) > 0);
  ShowMessage(LogFont.lfFaceName);
  Win32Check(ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, DC) = 1);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer user759588... This procedure gives the typeface name of a font that is installed in windows... but i am looking to get the typeface name of a font that isn't installed it is just in a folder... And that not tell above sorry.... the other question is how to get the windows name font like "arialblackno1.ttf" that have typeface ="arialblack"... sorry my friend my english is terrible...