# How to get a font name from a font file?

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fonts problem, typeface,windows name…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196286/fonts-problem-typeface-windows-name)

First I am looking to get the typeface name of a font that isn't installed, it is just in a folder.

And second question is how to get the Windows name font like "arialblackno1.ttf" that have typeface "arialblack".

Comment: you could edit your previous question, not post another one. This might be closed as exact duplicate.

Comment: Sorry deamon new here i never do that again... thanks

Comment: no problem; sometimes you just need to wait for the answer :)

Comment: Yes roddy is the same sorry...

Comment: not possible sure duplicate but i didn't know sorry hahaha

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, you can try to look into the registry, key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts.

Comment: OP wants to get the name from the font file somehow, not from the installed one. He mentioned this in his previous question.

Comment: deamon_x covers me... Ladislav but thanks...

Comment: okay, [link]http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/fontnamefromfile.aspx?fid=3897&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26#xx0xx[/link] might help, though written in C, but I think the matter is well explained there

Comment: Oh Too many C lang there i'll try...